# How to rewrite the default representation of an object or a class in Node.js?(just like __str__ and __repr__ of Python)

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to rewrite the default representation of an object or a class in Node.js?
Just like the function of `__str__` and `__repr__` of Python, how could I do the same thing while using JavaScript?

For example I have an object be like

```
obj={ arr: []};
```

If I use `console.log()` to print that object, the result will be `{arr:Array[0]}`.
What should I do if I want the code `console.log(obj)` return the arr of that object or a string or something else?